# I was never sent an e-mail verification e-mail for Pokemon Go. Is that going to be a problem?

Tags: pokemon-go

This is my second time creating a Pokemon Go account through Google. My first account stopped working after about 2 days. I tried to figure out why that happened and a friend asked if I had verified my e-mail account. But I never received an e-mail from Pokemon Go requesting verification. And, on the second time around, I have again not received that e-mail. Will that be an issue?

Comment: What do you mean by your account stopped working?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't receive a verification when loggin in with google and I don't think anyone else did.